# Use IIS Manager without Admin Rights

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, blazor

I have published a VS project to a folder, and now I want to host it on IIS.
But I can run IIS only with admin privileges. But I think that is a security issue, when the service run with admin prevs on Windows Server?
Is it possible to start IIS Manager without admin rights?!

Add:
It is a BlazorServer Project i want to host on IIS

Comment: Impossible as posts for decades prove. Don't waste your time. "I think that is a security issue" indicates that you need professional trainings on Windows Server security. Requiring IIS Manager to run by administrators is not a security issue at all, but a measure to protect security.